# Regex to match blocks of text defined by first line

Tags: regex, match, regex-negation

I have a file that I am looking to parse with regex. It has working so far for a number of different files, but this one requires something different. I have the following example text:

```
Test1 £4000 £5000
Here street
Here
UK
Test2 £2 £1000
There street
There
UK
Test3 £100 £1000
Haha street
Funnyville
Ireland
```

For the first one, for example, I need to get 3 things, `£4000`, `£5000` and

```
Test1
Here street
Here
UK
```

I am using the regex string `((.*)[^\x00-\x7F](.*)[^\x00-\x7F](.*)\n((.*\n){1,5}))` which goes some way to getting it right but only matches `Test1` and `Test3`. You can see this example at http://regex101.com/r/tT9pR8

I am trying to find a way to in this part `((.*\n){1,5})` to say that the line cannot contain a £ sign. (`[^\x00-\x7F]`). I have tried a couple of different ways, such as using `^[^\x00-x7F]` but none return any matches.

What is the best way to match this? Note: regex MUST be used, for anyone wondering.

EDIT: The text is actually surrounded by other text that should not be matched. The actual text resembles the below and using Robin's answer below matches the "START STRING" and "END STRING" into the first and last matches. "START STRING" and "END STRING" will be constants. See http://regex101.com/r/gM6vL0

```
START STRING
Test1 £4000 £5000
Here street
Here
UK
Test2 £2 £1000
There street
There
UK
Test3 £100 £1000
Haha street
Funnyville
Ireland
END STRING
```

EDIT 2: `END STRING` is actually more defined like `END STRING £4545 £4554` and therefore it matches Robin's pattern as can be seen at http://regex101.com/r/oC0xL2

Also there are other occurrences within the file that match the pattern, without being between `START STRING` and `END STRING`, and therefore should not be matched/

Answer (score 1):

**Easy solution**

Split your string: keep only the part between `START STRING` and `END STRING`, then apply

```
/^([^£]*)(£\d+)\s(£\d+)([^£]*)(?=^.*£|$)/gm
```

which will match your pattern without restriction

**Cool regex solution**

If you need to match these pattern *only right after a* `START STRING` (there are no real check that the end is `END STRING` and not just a line with `£` though), this should do the trick

```
/(?:START STRING|(?!\A)\G([^£]*)(£\d+)\s(£\d+)([^£]*)(?=^.*£|END STRING))/gm
```

This would catch `Test1`, `£4000`, `£5000` and

```
Here street
Here
UK
```

Demo here: http://regex101.com/r/gR4vM5

*Explanation*

```
(?:                              # non capturing parenthesis
    START STRING                 # either START STRING
|                                # or
    (?!\A)\G                     # end of the last match (but not the begin of the string)
    ([^£]*)(£\d+)\s(£\d+)([^£]*) # the wanted pattern
    (?=^.*£|END STRING))         # check that the next line either contains £ or START STRING
)
```

Comment: Sorry, see EDIT above. Forgot to mention this will be surrounded by other text.

Comment: @anothershrubery: Updated answer. This solution will however not account for the `START STRING`, meaning it won't search only inside these two start and end strings, which could lead to false positive if other data in your general string resemble this pattern. Is that an issue?

Comment: I just tested this out on the text and there are other places that the pattern does match so unfortunately not entirely plausible.

Comment: @anothershrubery: This should be better, updated answer.